# How can I iteratively generate all the possible combination of elements in sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, set

Let set `A=set([1,2,3]) and set B=set()` Now I need to iteratively generate all possible combinations like 

`set([1])
set([2])
set([3])
set([1,2])
set([1,3])
set([2,3])
set([1,2,3])`

I know blatantly I can use powergenerator recipe of itertools but the pseudo code is in below form to further conditions check(subset condition and Density condition)

```
a=set()
b=set([1,2,3])
for i in b-a:
    a=a|set([i])    
    for j in a: 
        print a-set([j])

        if den(a-set[j])>=0.6:#check density criteria
                # check if a-set([j]) is subset of a on ordering criteria
```

The print statement of above i.e, print a-set([j]) has given output as below

```
set([])
set([2])
set([1])
set([2, 3])
set([1, 3])
set([1, 2])
```

but I need to have output in below format

```
set([1])
set([2])
set([3])
set([2, 3])
set([1, 3])
set([1, 2])
set([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Why not just use the powerset recipe from itertools and filter out results you don't want?

Comment: @user2014111 did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

list(combinations(b, 1)) + list(combinations(b, 2)) + list(combinations(b, 3))
#[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try using iterto0ls to find the subset . [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools
a=[1,2,3]
subsets=[]
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in itertools.combinations(a,i):
        subsets.append(list(j))
print subsets

#output=[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

if set is method . u can link them,

```
map(set,subsets)
```